# After adding a Ruby Gem to a Gemfile and running bundle exec file.rb, I still get a file not found error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This is in my Gemfile:

`gem "trinsic_service_clients", "~> 1.1"`

This is at the top of my file named `instantiate_clients.rb`

`require_relative 'trinsic_service_clients`

However, when I run `bundle exec ruby instantiate_clients.rb` I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from instantiate_clients.rb:1:in `<main>'
instantiate_clients.rb:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/runner/DefenselessGrowlingExtraction/trinsic_service_clients (LoadError)
```

When I type `bundler exec gem which trinsic_service_clients` I get the following:

```
/home/runner/DefenselessGrowlingExtraction/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/trinsic_service_clients-1.1.5018/lib/trinsic_service_clients.rb
```

Comment: To use bundled gems, you have to have a [`Bundler.require`](https://bundler.io/guides/groups.html) somewhere in your app. Then you won't need this `require_relative`

Comment: Where "somewhere" = "before you try to use any of the gems from the gemfile"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev There's also the lazy version: `require 'bundler/setup'`.

Comment: @tadman: oh, nice, didn't know about this one. I was always doing `require "bundler"; Bundler.require`. It's almost in my muscle memory by now :)

Comment: Thanks, so in my script just add ‘require ‘bundler/setup’’ is there a downside if it is in every file?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require_relative` is for code *in* your application. It is not for code stored in gems. For those you should use `require` as it will look through `$LOAD_PATH` for the required files.

The easy way to make use of `Gemfile` is to load everything in via one shot:

```rb
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require(:default)
```

This not only adds the gem declarations, but does default `require` calls as well, as in this should already `require` your declared gem.

There's also `require 'bundler/setup'` which only adds the load paths, you still need to `require`, but this can help minimize load times if you may not necessarily need all the gems.

```rb
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'trinsic_service_clients'
```

This can be useful if your `Gemfile` has a lot of dependencies, but the scripts you're running may only use a small subset of them.